# Set predefined user password using Perl Script

Tags: perl, bash, shell

I have a user named "hduser" and the password of the user is say "xyz123". Now I need a automated script for it so that I can get logged in as hduser without prompting for it's password. For example I have written a perl script as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
system ("su hduser && <xyz123>");
```

I need to set the user password for hduser.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. You can [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/11880885/edit) your questions so you do not have to open a new one. And also make sure to read the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Answer (score 4):

You can't really do that in Perl. There might be some module at http://search.cpan.org which lets you do something as insecure as that.

My recommendation for you would be to configure "sudo" (see man sudo) and go with that.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility I would explore is opening a [pipe](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlopentut.html#Pipe-Opens) to the shell.  Then you should be able to do anything you can do from the terminal.